# Can 'git clean' move files to trash / recycle bin?

Tags: git, windows-10, recycle-bin, posh-git

I found `git clean -xdf`. And I like it, because it cleans up what may IDE created.

Today I was asked by a coworker: Can `git clean` move files to recycle bin instead of deleting the files?

I checked, `git clean` deleted some files in a test repository, but didn't move the files to trash.

I know there is option `-n` for dryrun.

**Edit:**

I'm on Windows 10 - that's why I have a recycle bin :).
And im using Git from PowerShell with PoSh-Git extension (to get auto completion).

Comment: FYI Windows isn't the only OS with a trash. Some Linux GUI environments have trash too (e.g., Ubuntu, KDE, ...) as do Macs. :)

Comment: Technically windows has “recycle bin”. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty fragile, (and isn't *git* recycling the file) but:

```
foreach ($s in git clean -xdn) {Remove-ItemSafely -Force $s.Remove(0,13)}
```

Caveats:

1) It'll just delete the file if there's no Recycle Bin for the drive. 
2) It'll break if the output of `git clean -xdn` changes because `$s.Remove(0,13)` is removing the first 13 characters of each line of output.
3) You may have to run `Install-Module Recycle` as an administrator on any given machine first.

A git plugin that returns .NET objects is preferable for something like this.  (Because then you could `remove-itemsafely $s.FileName`, for example)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recipe for a unix alias that does exactly that.
 https://coderwall.com/p/g16jpq/keep-your-git-directory-clean-with-git-clean-and-git-trash

You could probably adapt it to powershell pretty easily. It seems like the core is

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

which will list your untracked files. I'm not a PowerShell expert however so I'll decline to make an alias myself.

Also, from what I can tell there is no soft option native to git clean.

Answer (score 0):

For linux the mv command does not support moving keeping directory structure
My pragmatic approach for linux would sth like be

```
~> cp -R repo/ repo_bak/ #repo_bak will contain also a copy of .git/ folder
~> cd repo_bak/
~/repo_bak>git ls-files|xargs rm #remove files known to git
~/repo_bak> cd ../repo/
~/repo>git clean -dxf #do this if you are sure repo_bak/ has all you need
```